# RewriteRule redirects to full website url (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I try to redirect my dynamic url to a static url. 
I almost achieved this goal. But after opening the static url it will redirect to thefull path of my server. For example:

Actual link (dynamic)

`https://example.com/product?id=755&supermarket=albert-heijn&product=ah-roerbak-hollands-brocc-pomp-spitskool`

desired link (static)

`https://example.com/product/755/albert-heijn/ah-roerbak-hollands-brocc-pomp-spitskool`

Result (static redirects to)

`https://example.com/home/name/public_html/product/755/albert-heijn/ah-roerbak-hollands-brocc-pomp-spitskool/`

My .htaccess is  located inside my public_html folder, and there are no other .htaccess files on the server.

```
RewriteEngine on
# convert static url

RewriteRule /product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ product.php?id=$1&supermarket=$2&name=$3



<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
RewriteBase /
```

Or, if not works,

```
RewriteBase /home/name/public_html/
```

Comment: Didn’t work for me. Tried both and placed right above rewriterule